# Understanding "pallias"

Tags: british-english, slang, understanding, irish-english

What does "pallias" mean in the passage:

UNCLE PAT. Cow Gum! Now there’s a scent to stir the soul. September,
nineteen hundred and eleven… I was seven years old. Pat, Maggie,
Arthur, Frank and me, all sharing a pallias in the stable, with fourteen
cousins. It was one of those magical, crisp mornings when the sun rises
and softens all the sharp edges of the world.

Comment: Usually spelled 'palliasse' where I come from, a straw mattress.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Maybe some letters are lost?

From Oxford ALD:

> **palliasse**
>   **pal·li·asse [palliasse palliasses]
>
>   BrE [ˈpæliæs]  NAmE [pælˈjæs]**
>   noun
>   a cloth bag filled with straw, used for sleeping on
>   Syn: pallet

Origin:

> Word Origin:
>   early 16th cent. (originally Scots): from French paillasse, based on Latin palea ‘straw’.

https://www.oxfordlearnersdictionaries.com/definition/english/palliasse?q=palliasse